# jQuery on click not targeting the correct element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with jQuery click function.

When the nav is clicked, I wish to remove all `active` classes on the `li`, then add the class `active` to `$(this)` and then, usually, the world is a happy place but not this time.

It could be something simple but I have tried a dozen options and even rewrote some of my css to make sure it is targeting the right element.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<header>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Health Benefits Ohio</p>
    <p>Heliping Ohioans with healthcare choices</p>
</div>
</header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About OAHU</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Find an Agent</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Agents Login</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="slideshow">
<section id="rotator">

</section>
</div>
<div class="body">
<header>

</header>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
<div class="footerFill"></div>
</footer>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('nav > ul > li > a').on('click', function() {
       $('nav > ul > li > a').parent().removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
width: 100%;
height: 55px;
background: #0c5b78;
/*background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0% 0% 100%, from(#0c5b78), to(#c4c4c4));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0c5b78, #c4c4c4);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #0c5b78, #c4c4c4);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #0c5b78, #c4c4c4);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #0c5b78, #c4c4c4);*/
border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

nav > ul {
width: 960px;
height: 55px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li {
height: 55px;
width: 182px;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 55px;
text-align: center;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
color: #fff;
float: left;
display: block;
margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 black;
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.active {
height: 50px;
margin-top: 5px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
color: #4b4b4b;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #c7c7c7;
}

.active > a {
color: #4b4b4b;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
height: 50px;
width: 172px;
display: block;
margin-left: 5px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
-ms-transition: all .3s ease;
-o-transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav > ul > li > a:hover {
color: #4b4b4b;
height: 50px;
width: 172px;
display: block;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px #c7c7c7;
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
margin-top: 5px;
display: block;
}
```

If anyone could give me some tips or good resources I could utilize to solve my problem then I would greatly appreciate it! I am new to jQuery but I am guessing that some how my css is causing this problem but I could be wrong.

[Live site](http://healthbenefitsohio.com/redesign/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want to change these lines:

```
$('nav > ul > li > a').parent().removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

to:

```
$('nav > ul > li').removeClass('active');
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

You should also add an href to your links:

```
<a href="#">About OAHU</a>
```

And this to the end of your click function:

```
return false;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and I'll give this a try right now!   I did try this and it still is not adding that class. This is a weird problem to be honest with you and I have never had this problem before with such a simple function.

Comment: Ahh I normally just add the url right away but I have the entire website done so I was focusing on getting the structure finished to convert the content over. This was indeed the problem and thanks a million for spotting that out!

Comment: Good job Zig. +1 -- Here's a [working jsFiddle of zigdawgydawg's answer](http://jsfiddle.net/cLnBT/)

Comment: Thanks gibberish for adding a fiddle on this!